# Recieve Variable From php file Using fopen?

Tags: php, get, fopen, file-get-contents

I've been working on a blogging system and I wish to receive information from external php files for a post's Title and Content, here is my code:

**External (Blog Post's Content) File: *03-20-2018-This-Is-A-Test.php***

```
<?php
$Title = 'This is a test!';
$Date = '03-20-2018';
$Content = 'Blog Post&#39;s content!';
?>
```

**Client Side Page For Viewing Blog Posts: *Post Home.php***

```
<?php
$Title = '';
$Date = '';
$Content = '';

$GetDate = $_GET['d'];
$GetTitle = $_GET['t'];

$postPath = "Posts/$GetDate"."-"."$GetTitle.php";

$postFile = fopen($postPath,"rt");
$postContent = fgets($postFile,filesize($postPath));
?>

<!--Some HTML-->

<h2><? echo $Title; ?></2>
<b><? echo $Date; ?></b>
<p><? echo $Content; ?></p>

<!--Some More HTML-->

<? fclose($postFile); ?>
```

**Client's Page URL: *example.com/Post%20Home.php?d=03-20-2018&t=This-Is-A-Test***

**Reformatted as: *example.com/03-20-2018/This-Is-A-Test***

---

As you can see, I am using GET parameters to call the file that I wish to collect the information from.
I have tried using **fopen** which I wasn't able to get to work. Also **include** is forbidden with the particular server hosts I am using.

I am open to using **file_get_contents** if someone is able to help me get it to work.

**Note: I have confirmed that my calling URL is correct and I get no errors from my php**

---

So, I am trying to use **fopen** to collect the data of **$Title $Date $Content** from the file; **03-20-2018-This-Is-A-Test.php** and use that information in the Client Side file; **Post Home.php**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer using require().